# Como puedo comparar 2 campos de la misma tabla con laravel?

Tags: laravel, array

Primero que todo Buen dia y gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer estoy haciendo mi proyecto de titulo y recien estoy empesando a aprender laravel y no se me ocurre como hacer esta funcion.
Esta es la base de datos en los dato que quiero comparar es el 'sku' quiero que se compare si se repite algún 'sku' y me lo guarde:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí busco los registro por mes en este caso es el mes 10 y quiero que todos los registros de 'sku' repetidos me los mande a '$repetido'

```
$inventarios = Inventario::whereMonth('created_at','=','10')->get();

        $repetido=  ??;
        return view('inventarios.show',['inventarios'=>$inventarios]);
```

La idea es que me mande todos los datos para poder agregarlos a la vista y que quede algo asi este es un ejemplo de como me gustaría mandar los datos por que luego igual tengo que comparar que el dato 'pies' sea distinto.
[image: introduce tu texgto aqui]
en la vista muestro los datos de esta forma

```
@foreach ($inventarios as $inventario)
            <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{ $inventario->sku }}</th>
                    <td>{{ $inventario->talla }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $inventario->pies }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $inventario->caja }}</td>
                    @foreach ($inventario->tienda as $tiendas)
                        <td>{{ $tiendas->name }}</td>
                    @endforeach
                    
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Es adecuado al sitio, facilitar la labor a quienes puedan responderte, creando un ejemplo mínimo y completo. Para esto, si creas la tabla como texto, facilita la labor, pues se puede copiar, pegar y adaptar, para no tener que hacer todo el trabajo. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificar la misma. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre los comentarios vertidos, **edito**:

Puedes proceder de esta forma:

- Agrupamos de forma concatenada tantos los ids, como los skus y alguna columna mas
- Ponemos el filtro del mes que ya tienes
- Agrupamos por la columna sku
- Filtramos mediante un having para solo obtener aquellos skus que se encuentren mas de 1 vez almacenados

  ```
    $consultaDuplicados = Inventario::selectRaw("
                                                    GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR '\n')  AS ids,
                                                    GROUP_CONCAT(sku SEPARATOR '\n') AS skus,
                                                    GROUP_CONCAT(otraColumna SEPARATOR '\n')  AS algoMas
                                                ")
                                    ->whereMonth('created_at', 10)
                                    ->groupBy('sku')
                                    ->havingRaw('COUNT(sku) > ?', [1])
                                    ->get();
  ```

Consideremos que esta solución nos dejaría cada grupo de skus repetidos dentro de la misma celda, ya es trabajo posterior manejar esos datos según corresponda